# How can I bind non-ascii keys with a utf-8-encoded .vimrc?

Tags: vim

### The problem

I have a Scandinavian keyboard, and I want to [bind my <kbd>Æ</kbd>, <kbd>Ø</kbd> and <kbd>Å</kbd> keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aIlluminated_keyboard_2.JPG). For example, [I use <kbd>Ø</kbd> as leader](https://github.com/lstor/vimfiles-lstor/blob/master/vimrc#L18):

```
" ok, works:
let mapleader = "ø"
```

When the `.vimrc` is encoded in `latin1`, this works like a charm. However, I want to use `:set enc=utf8` in my `.vimrc`, and then the mappings stop working:

```
" whoops, doesn't work:
let mapleader = "ø"
set encoding=utf-8
```

I *presume* this is because the `.vimrc` is written as utf-8, and that Vim is unable to parse or map the multi-byte characters.

What I want is to be able to use my non-ascii keymappings while still defaulting to utf-8 for all files other than `.vimrc`. (Storing `.vimrc` as `latin1` would be an acceptable solution, but I haven't figured out a way to do it.)

### Approaches that *don't* work

I have tried all kinds of things, and none of the following work:

- Modelines that set `encoding` and/or `fileencoding` for `.vimrc`.
- Mapping the keys to `"\u00f8"` and similar values instead.
- Putting non-valid utf-8 sequences in `.vimrc` to force defaulting to `latin1`.
- Various autocommands to set `encoding` and/or `fileencoding` for `.vimrc`.
- Opening Vim with `--cmd "set encoding=latin1"`, because I edit my `.vimrc` too frequently for that to be feasible.

**How can I use both** `set encoding=utf-8` ***and* map my non-ascii keys?**

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this all my mappings work with `let mapleader = "ø"` and `set encoding=utf-8`

Comment: @FDinoff Even after writing the file with `enc=utf-8`?

Comment: The leader key still works even after writing the file with `enc=utf-8`

Comment: @FDinoff Thank you for testing. Which operating system and Vim version are you using?

Comment: Mac osx 10.8 vim 7.3 Included patches: 1-244, 246-762. (I'm generating `ø` with `option-o` if that matters)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid utf-8? utf-8 includes a large part of the character sets in use in the world, including the characters you want to bind. My whole environment uses utf-8 everywhere and I have no problem using `ø` as `<leader>`.

Comment: @romainl I *don't* want to avoid utf-8. The problem arose when I *did* `set enc=utf-8`. I want to use utf-8 as much as possible, but I also want my key bindings to work.

Comment: What is the default value of `'encoding'`?

Comment: @romainl latin1. But I just found out the problem now, it is caused by ultisnips. Disabling ultisnips resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the ultisnips plugin. Disabling ultisnips will resolve the issue.

Comment: Good (and surprising) catch. You should submit a bug report.